# Set z transform position of an instantiated GameObject sprite in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, z-index, instantiation

Is there an easy (shorter) way to set the z transform position of an instantiated game object (sprite) in unity? I want to set each instance to 2 for now.
Here's the one line of code I am using, I just wanted to set the z position and it seems cumbersome to do it this way - ignore the first line as I am only including it to demonstrate how the GameObject has been instantiated:

```
GameObject laser = Instantiate(laserPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
laser.transform.position = new Vector3(laser.transform.position.x, laser.transform.position.y, 2);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what would speak against `GameObject laser = Instantiate(laserPrefab, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, 2), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;` ?

Comment: Thank you derHugo - that is a more condensed way to write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simpler way of doing this, but you can create method to make your code assigning new position shorter. For example, creating method like this:

```
Vector3 SetZ(Vector3 vector, float z)
{
    vector.z = z;
    return vector;
}
```

Would let you to set new object's position like this

```
laser.transform.position = SetZ(laser.transform.position, 2);
```

You have to use method, because trying to do it directly, using property would result in compile time error.

```
transform.position.z = 2;
```

Results in error: `CS1612: Cannot modify the return value of 'Transform.position' because it is not a variable`

Comment: Why `vector.x = z;` though?

Answer (score 0):

There are some extension methods on Vector3 that might make it a bit more easy to read. But I don't think it will get much shorter than what you wrote:

Like Vector3.MoveTowards

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html

But the short answer might be this: No.

A Vector(2/3) is a struct. In this case its made safe for the user by unity and made fully readonly, as you can't really assign values to a struct, because that would result in a new instance of the struct. So you cannot do assignments like laser.transform.position.z = 2. You will always have to create a new Vector.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies further for me.